# Can't build the filter for AD users

Tags: c#, search, active-directory

I'm looking for events from changing AD on the fly. There is a single example AFAICC that everybody using. It's ok for a separated OU containing users only, but when I've set it for the entire domain, too many events occuring, so I need to filter user's only changes. Currently I have an `(objectClass=*)` filter for the `SearchRequest` method and it works fine. But when I change it to `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))` or `(sAMAccountType=805306368)` or anything else, I've got a runtime `DirectoryOperationalException`. Why?

I have try to change syntax, after that I've copy-pasted some examples I have found in the Net directly into my code, but alas.

```
string searchFilter = "(sAMAccountType=805306368)";

SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest(
    dn, //root the search here
    searchFilter, //"(objectClass=*)", // very inclusive
    scope, //any scope works
    null //we are interested in all attributes
);
```

Comment: I don't see any issues with the code you've shown. Can you show more of your code, like where you actually perform the search, and on which line the exception happens? And the full message from the exception too.

Comment: Can you please state your main goal ? What you want to achieve ?

Comment: The main goal is to build replication request to ADMT upon a vital changes made on Windows DC with user's account. I'm using this code:http://dunnry.com/blog/ImplementingChangeNotificationsInNET.aspx. I've changed unworking CreateConnection("localhost") to LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(sets.domainName) and did experiments within ChangeNotifier class described before. Probaly there are some external issues?

Comment: Exception is here: `private void Notify(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            //since our search is long running, we don't want to use EndSendRequest
            PartialResultsCollection prc = _connection.GetPartialResults(result);`

Comment: Once again, it works fine with `filter = "(objectClass=*)". `

Comment: Can you update your question with the full text from the exception?

Comment: The error was "the server cannont... something". I have reworked the code, so I'm using the wildcard filter and checking for interesting events by myself. Had hope it's a simple question like "change ur domain for..", but since it's not, I just have no time for deep research on the problem (. And yes, I've try the full domain admin privilegies, it doesn't help (

Answer (score 0):

I am using this .. This code finds the persons details by first name, middle Initial, Last name. Not sure if you are looking for this.

https://lastloop.blogspot.com/2019/07/list-of-all-active-directory-properties.html

```
public List<Person> FindPersonDetails(Person objPerson)
        {
            string lname = string.Empty, fname = string.Empty, mname = string.Empty, MSID = string.Empty;
            fname = objPerson.FirstName;
            lname = objPerson.LastName;
            mname = objPerson.MiddleName;
            MSID = objPerson.MSID;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("DisplayName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("GivenName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("SurName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("MSID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("employeeid", typeof(string));

            //DirectoryEntry _objDirectoryEntry;
            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
            if (lname != null && lname != "")
            {
                if (mname != null && mname != "")
                    searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(givenName={0}*)(DisplayName={1}*)(middlename={2}*))", fname, lname, mname);
                else
                    searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(givenName={0}*)(DisplayName={1}*))", fname, lname);
            }
            else if (MSID != null && MSID != "")
            {
                searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(cn={0}))", MSID);
            }
            else
            {
                if (mname != null && mname != "")
                    searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(givenName={0}*)(middlename={1}*))", fname, mname);
                else
                    searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(givenName={0}*))", fname);
            }
            SearchResultCollection allResults;
            //searcher.SizeLimit = 100;
            searcher.Asynchronous = true;
            //searcher.ClientTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7);
            allResults = searcher.FindAll();
            try
            {
                if (allResults.Count >= 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < allResults.Count; i++)
                    {
                        DirectoryEntry deMembershipUser = allResults[i].GetDirectoryEntry();
                        deMembershipUser.RefreshCache();
                        dt.Rows.Add(
                            (string)deMembershipUser.Properties["displayname"].Value ?? "Not Available",
                            (string)deMembershipUser.Properties["givenName"].Value ?? "Not Available",
                            (string)deMembershipUser.Properties["sn"].Value ?? "Not Available",
                            (string)deMembershipUser.Properties["cn"].Value ?? "Not Available",
                            (string)deMembershipUser.Properties["mail"].Value ?? "Not Available",
                            (string)deMembershipUser.Properties["employeeid"].Value ?? "Not Available"
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
            catch ()
            {

            }
            dt.DefaultView.Sort = "DisplayName ASC";
            dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
            List<Person> objPersonList = new List<Person>();
            if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    Person obj = new Person();

                    obj.DisplayName = dr["displayname"].ToString();
                    //obj.GivenName = dr["givenName"].ToString();
                    //obj.SurName = dr["SurName"].ToString();
                    obj.Email = dr["Email"].ToString();
                    obj.MSID = dr["MSID"].ToString();
                    //obj.employeeid = dr["employeeid"].ToString();
                    objPersonList.Add(obj);
                }
            }

            return objPersonList;
        }

  public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string MSID { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; } 
        public string Email { get; set; }
        //public string employeeid { get; set; } 
    }
```